# list view taking up more space than needed

Tags: android

This is my custom dialog which consist of the following

list view,button and finally a textview used when the list is empty.

My problem is the listview seems to take up more space than it needs to when only 1 item exists.

The image below shows this.

[image]

My XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRaffles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bCloseDialog"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCloseDialog"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/alert_dialog_button_style"
        android:text="Close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRaffleEmpty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Raffle Code Found With That Search"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried the following.
List View height on wrap_content, 0dp does not help.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it, I used linear layouts instead

Comment: that is not your list view, it is empty space. that's what `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you fixed this with LinearLayout but to answer your question, the reason it appears as if your listview is taking up too much space is because you used layout_alignParentBottom="true" if you want the button to appear below the listview you would need to use layout_below="@id/lvRaffles" You also have two elements aligned to parentTop, which can cause the elements to overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this will help me next time I encounter such problems